# Grub change loopback amount?

Tags: linux, loop-device

I'm having an issue with loopback. It looks like there is only 8. I did a search and apparently the problem is grub by default only has 8 loopback (devices?). If i look in /dev/ i see loop 0-7 so that does seem to make sense.

How do i change the amount of loopbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how GRUB comes into this, as you don't explain the connection, but you can increase the number of simultaneously usable loop devices using the `loop` module (without a reboot).

```
modprobe loop max_loop=64
```

You can then manually make more loop devices with `mknod` like so:

```
mknod -m 660 /dev/loop8 b 7 8
```

Make sure the new loop device is owned by `root:disk` for consistency:

```
chown root:disk /dev/loop8
```

In the `mknod` command:

- The major number for loop devices is `7`. That's what the `7` represents (constant for all loop devices)
- The minor number is unique for each loop device. It starts from `0` for `/dev/loop0`, 1 for `/dev/loop1`, and so on.

The `8` represents the minor number for `/dev/loop8`.
So, for `/dev/loop9`, you would increase the minor number by one:

```
mknod -m 660 /dev/loop9 b 7 9
```

Here's a shell command to create a large number of them at one time (starting with `10` through `254`):

```
for i in {10..254}; do
    mknod -m 660 /dev/loop$i b 7 $i
    chown root:disk /dev/loop$i
done
```

Comment: I don't know either as what i saw didnt explain but i did see something saying grub defaults to 8. But good answer. The mknod line definitely does work. modprobe didn't. I tried restarting and 8 is still available

Comment: @acidzombie24 - `max_loop` probably doesn't do what you think it does, it only increases the number of *possible* loop devices. It doesn't actually create them.

Comment: ah i see. Its not that much trouble to write a script to create them all